# What I have to do order to have this URL "/#namepage" with Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, url, route-provider

```
function config($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/',{
            templateUrl: '../templates/main/login/login.html'
        })
        .when('/login',{
            templateUrl: '../templates/main/login/login.html'
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo:"/" });
}
```

Structure:

```
- application(php stuff)

- webroot
-- app
--- app.js

-- templates
--- main
---- login
----- login.html

index.html (with angularjs libs)
```

I've got a problem, because if I write the url as "local.domain.com/#login"
it becames "local.domain.com/#/login"

login.html:

```
<div>LOGIN test template</div>
```

I don't understand what is wrong with my little code

PS: I'm trying to move frontend from EJS (js lib) to Angularjs

Comment: Try without the dots - `templateUrl: 'templates/main/login/login.html'`, and the link should be `<a href="#/login">Login</a>`.

Comment: What's wrong with `/#/login`? Why is it so important for it to be `/#login`? Nothing's wrong with your code as far as I can tell. I think you're just expecting your way and seeing Angular's way.

Comment: you need to to `$routeProvider
        .when('/',{
            templateUrl: '../templates/main/login/login.html'
        })
        .when('login',{
            templateUrl: '../templates/main/login/login.html'
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo:"/" });` then it will work like you want..but i would not follow routing without / before it

Comment: @Jason Sweeit because the previous url was like that /#namePage

Comment: @pankajparkar I've done exactly the same of you... where's the difference?

Comment: check your and mine code you added `.when('/login')` i added `when('login')`.check my code is working or not

Comment: Ok, sorry, I didn't notice that... btw, previously I tried that